# Efficient way to provide cached tiles?

Tags: openstreetmap, cache, png

I am creating an app in Android that requires cached areas. I allow the user to cache an area of reasonable size. The server provides these tiles in a zip in the format /z/x/y.png.

I took a (very) naive approach and simply wrote a python script to grab the images from the localhost using apache2 with mod_tile (127.0.0.1/osm/z/x/y.png), save to a directory, then zip.

Under a load test, this failed terribly. Is there a more efficient way to create the png files locally? (Mapnik api and python?) Or is a queue for users an absolute necessity to prevent server overload?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your actual problem. Do you want help with the downloading of tiles, or Creating the tiles, or storing the tile? Furthermore, what server/service are you using?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but I suspect the answer is [MapBox's](https://www.mapbox.com/foundations/an-open-platform/) [mbtiles](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec) format. It uses an SQLite database.

Comment: Me too, is the issue the tile creation process, the tile caching process, or the download/extraction process .. If you want the tiles, just populate the cache and zip the whole directory. In Geowebcache it is called a Seeding Operation, you can also use TileCache ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GeoWebCache or Tilecache to generate your tiles. The Process is called Seeding .. You need to be aware of the different file storage schemas ..

References:

> [TileCache Seeding](http://tilecache.org/docs/README.html#seeding-your-tilecache)
>
> [Discussion on the Tilecache Disk Format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27273/what-is-the-tiling-scheme-of-tilecache)
>
> [GeoWebCache Seeding](http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/webinterface/seed.html)

There is also this process [Exporting and extracting the tiles from TileMill](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/711) That may suit as well ..

With GeoWebCache, accessing the data store directly is problematic, but you should be able to build a script to pull the tiles without any load issues, it is very efficient.

Once you have your scripts in place, you can reseed and re-download your zip files to keep your app up to date.